# Can anyone help me to access my eth account in metamask using infura in android

Tags: web3j, infura

My question is about accessing my eth account in metamask using infura in android

Comment: You can use Firefox browser in android and get Metamsk extension and use it :)

Comment: I mean, I'm developing an android app. And I'm trying to deploy my contract, but I can't get my wallet credentials. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: to look at your account you only need your address, if you need to do transactions then you need your private key, both can be obtained from metamask

Comment: I think metamask will not work with any android app. How about managing user wallets using their private keys? if they provide private keys, then you can manage everything.. or how about doing as like this? https://trustwallet.com/

Comment: I solved my problem by getting the private key of my eth account in metamask. Thank you :)